# How do i share my network(hospital network) to my headless R-pi over ethernet?

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, raspberrypi

I have internet connection on my laptop through the WLAN card and i have to log into the network with temporary codes. Currently running Ubuntu 16.04. So, i want to set up an ad-hoc network over the Ethernet interface to the r-pi and be able to ssh into it. i have put Raspbian on the pi and ssh is enabled, but i have no idea what its IP address is as my OS isn't configured to be a DHCP server. Not sure where to go from here. Does anyone know how i could accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

First get the address of your gateway. This should be in format `192.168.AAA.BBB`.

Enter following commands on your Ubuntu machine:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward > /dev/null
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE -s 192.168.2.0/24
sudo ip route del default
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.AAA.BBB
```

On your Raspberry Pi:

change the file `/etc/network/interfaces` following way:

```
iface eth0 inet static
            address 192.168.2.201
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            gateway 192.168.2.1
```

edit `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` :

```
ddns-update-style none;

option domain-name "domain.local";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.2.201;

default-lease-time 60;
max-lease-time 72;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# wpad
option local-proxy-config code 252 = text;

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.2;
  option routers 192.168.2.201;
  option local-proxy-config "http://192.168.2.201/wpad.dat";
}
```

Now you should be able to ssh via Ethernet interface.
In the ssh session enter following commands on your PI:

```
$ sudo ip route del default
$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.2
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'nameserver 192.168.AAA.BBB' > /etc/resolv.conf"
```

Replace the `192.168.AAA.BBB` with the gateway from your wlan network.

Your RPi now should have internet connection.